# Popping up a dialog/message after NSIS install in silent mode

Tags: installation, nsis

I have an NSIS installer set to run in silent mode. This works very well.

I've had a customer request for an informational pop up once the install has complete...but still wants the installer portion to be silent!

I realize this is counter intuitive.

**That being said is there away to override the silent at the end of the install?**

I currently set the installer attribute below at the beginning of the .nsi script

```
SilentInstall silent
```

Comment: SilentInstall sets a installer attribute, not a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle silent mode on or off in `.onInit` with `SetSilent` but once that function returns the UI mode cannot be changed.

The simple solution is to simply use one of the [Banner](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Examples/Banner/Example.nsi) or [Splash](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Examples/AdvSplash/Example.nsi) plug-ins at the end of your last `Section` to display a message/image.

Or you can create a fake silent mode with a minimal UI that only displays the progress bar:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Var Silent

Function .onInit
${If} ${Silent}
    SetSilent Normal ; Turn off real silent mode
    SetAutoClose True
    StrCpy $Silent 1 ; Fake silent mode
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Page Components SkipPageIfSilent
Page Directory SkipPageIfSilent
Page InstFiles "" TweakInstfilesPage

Function SkipPageIfSilent
IntCmp $Silent 0 +2
    Abort
FunctionEnd

Function TweakInstfilesPage
${If} $Silent <> 0
    SetSilent Silent ; Make IfSilent return true
    FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    GetDlgItem $0 $0 0x403 ; Show details button
    ShowWindow $0 0
    System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(p$0,@r1)' ; NSIS v3+
    System::Call 'USER32::GetWindowRect(p$HWNDPARENT,@r2)' ; NSIS v3+
    System::Call '*$1(i,i.r3,i,i)'
    System::Call '*$2(i.r5,i.r6,i.r7,ir3r8)'
    IntOp $5 $7 - $5 ; Width
    IntOp $6 $8 - $6 ; Height
    System::Call 'USER32::SetWindowPos(p$HWNDPARENT,p,i,i,ir5,ir6,i0x12)'
    SetDetailsView Hide
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Section
Sleep 333
Sleep 333
Sleep 333
Sleep 333
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks Anders, I'll take a look at this and report back!